# Header value to be returned based on "Current Date" column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Role Selection]

I have been looking for this formula but could not figure for quite a while.

We have growing team that will periodically move to a new position based on their performance.

I need to have the updated "Role" based on the "Updated Date".

Logic for first sample at column H:K.

Date stated from column C - E would be their effective date.

For rep 1, he was effectively as Focal from 1 Jun, moved to Call on 1 Jul and move to Lateshift on 1 Aug till now.

Rep 1 was a "Call" team on 3 July hence current role = Call

Answer (score 1):

Just use `MATCH` with the "exact or next smallest" match-type inside `INDEX`.

For example:
`=INDEX($A$1:$D$4, 1, MATCH($B7, $A2:$D2, 1))`

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks! It resolved but not entirely maybe because of my simple example. How to match if the array match was not arrange in such? Meaning position of rep did not follow 1 till 3.

Comment: In that case try ```=INDEX($A$1:$D$4, 1, MATCH(TRUE, $A2:$D2<=$B7, 0))```